# Rails: UnknownAttribute Error - How do I make my model "know" attributes in the first place in Rails6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

in Rails6 I think one comment mentioned that I can only use Migrations to assign attributes to a model. (i.e. the columns from my migration for a model table are automatically assigned to that model)

Is that correct?

And the Error Message

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError
```

is spawned because for instance some view uses an unknown attribute in a form ? That is: one, which has no column through a migration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last part of your question, this specific error (UnknownAttributeError) happens on an unknown attribute during [mass assignment](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveModel/UnknownAttributeError.html).

If you were to call it straight on the instance the error would be different (NoMethodError I believe) because Rails has no way of knowing if you tried accessing an attribute or a method.

Comment: I don't come behind the reason for the error. I renamed the field in the view such that it fits the column name in the migration.

Say, wasn't there (a long time ago) where one would use attr_accessor in the model definition? I guess Rails now automatically creates the getters/setters for instance methods automagically from the migration.

Comment: Not from the migration, when Rails boots it queries the database for it's structure I believe. So it doesn't rely on the migration files or even schema.rb. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f10d814140cd48612d90ca2e4839abab567ce2df/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L569

Comment: The migartions are used to help you change the database through time but Rails doesn't rely on them to create the attributes

Answer (score 1):

> I can only use migrations to assign attributes to a model.

Technically, no. But in practice - yes. On startup Rails loads schema of whatever DB it is connected to and generates attributes for your models. You could open a `psql` console (or equivalent for your DB of choice), add a column manually and then this attribute would appear in your model on next schema refresh. But you shouldn't do that. All your schema changes should be in migrations.

> And the Error Message `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError` is spawned because for instance some view uses an unknown attribute in a form ?

Yes.

> That is: one, which has no column through a migration ?

No. You can define transient attributes (those that do not get persisted and therefore don't require a DB column and migrations).

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :skip_extended_validation # this attribute is not persisted, but can be set from forms, etc.
end
```